# Reduce Queries by optimizing _sets in Django

Tags: python, django

The follow results in 4 db hits. Since lines 3 & 4 are just filtering what I grabbed in line 2, what do I need to change so it doesn't hit the db again?

```
page = get_object_or_404(Page, url__iexact = page_url)
installed_modules = page.module_set.all()
navigation_links = installed_modules.filter(module_type=ModuleTypeCode.MODAL)
module_map = dict([(m.module_static_object.key, m) for m in installed_modules])
```

Comment: Why does `installed_modules = ` include the `.all()` method?  Further, why are you building a dictionary?  What more is going to happen with this collection?

Comment: @S.Lott this is part of a much bigger function. Regardless of what comes after, I'm just trying to optimize these lines so I dont hit the db more than twice. Once to grab the page object, and then once to grab the related modules to that page. Then I can use the related set to build the dict, etc...  I'm using all to get all the modules that are related to this page. But if it's unnecessary, I'd remove it.

Comment: what about `navigation_links = installed_modules.filter(module_type=ModuleTypeCode.MODAL).select_related('module_static_object__key')`? [Learn more about select_related.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

Comment: @Brendan: (1) Please add information by **updating** the question so it's one, coherent whole.  (2) "But if it's unnecessary, I'd remove it".  You should try removing `.all()` to see what happens. (3) Creating a dictionary still seems needless.  Please **update** the question to explain why the dictionary is getting built.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django [querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy), so the following line doesn't hit the database:

```
installed_modules = page.module_set.all()
```

The query isn't executed until you iterate over the queryset in this line:

```
module_map = dict([(m.module_static_object.key, m) for m in installed_modules])
```

So the code you posted only looks like 3 database queries hits to me, not 4.

Since you are fetching all of the modules from the database already, you could filter the navigation links using a list comprehension instead of another query:

```
navigation_links = [m for m in installed_modules if m.module_type == ModuleTypeCode.MODAL]
```

You would have to do some benchmarking to see if this improved performance. It looks like it could be premature optimisation to me.

You might be doing one database query for each module where you fetch `module_static_object.key`. In this case, you could use [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related).

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of premature optimization. 4 DB queries for a page load is not bad. The idea is to use as few queries as possible, but you're never going to get it down to 1 in every scenario. The code you have there doesn't seem off-the-wall in terms of needlessly creating queries, so it's highly probable that it's already as optimized as you'll be able to make it.

Comment: How do you know how expensive the queries are? The question he asked is reasonable.

Comment: Chris - this is the beginning to a pretty long function. When I look at all the queries in the function, I think this is where I can save the most. that's why I'm trying to optimize.

Comment: Well, the point is that there's not really any savings to be had here. Getting the initial page object is a query unto its own. Getting the `installed_modules` is another query. Getting `navigation_links` is necessarily yet another query (even though it's building off the query for `installed_modules`), unless you do something like create a list comprehension from installed_modules. That'll save a query, but leaves you with a static list instead of a queryset. At the most you save one query, which is virtually meaningless in the grand scheme, considering the lost functionality.